# Android ListView: get item's position from its value?

Tags: android, listview

I'm new to Android and Java. I was wondering if there is a way to find the position of a ListView item by its value.

For example:
If I have an item in my ListView that displays the string "Product 1108" How would I get the position of "Product 1108"?

```
private void updateListView() {
    final ListView lvCheckList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvCheckList);
    Map<String, ?> keys = checkListData.getAll();

    ArrayList<String> checkListStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : keys.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getKey().equals(currentList + entry.getValue())) {
                checkListStrings.add((String) entry.getValue());
            }
            if (entry.getKey().equals(currentList + entry.getValue() + "Checked")) {
                //set Item to checked / unchecked

            }
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> checkListArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked,
                checkListStrings);
                lvCheckList.setAdapter(checkListArrayAdapter);  
                }
```

This code gets the the the items stored in SharedPreferences and displays them in the ListView. Don't ask me why it works, it just does.

Now see this line:

```
if (entry.getKey().equals(currentList + entry.getValue() + "Checked")) {
                //set Item to checked / unchecked
    }
```

What I want to happen here is to set the list item to either checked or unchecked, but I don't think that it's possible because the listview has not been populated yet. So in the ArrayAdapter I need to sort through the items of the listview, find the item with whatever value I'm looking for, and get the position of that item so I can use this code:

```
lvCheckList.setItemChecked(position, value);
```

Hopefully this made sense.

Comment: how are you getting the value?

Comment: The value is loaded from SharedPreferences.

Comment: why do you need it? (i don't see what case you can have where you know the display value but you don't have the position at the same time)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `BaseAdapter` you should have a something like an `ArrayList` storing items, which you could use the `indexOf(obj)` method on.

If you're using an `ArrayAdapter` you could use `getPosition(obj);`

Here is an example of looping over an `ArrayAdapter` (let me know if you use something else):

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new YourCustomArrayAdapter();
for(int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++)
    System.out.println(String.format("String \"%s\" has an index of %d", adapter.getItem(i), i);
```

This does not use the method `getPosition()` because our loop feeds us a position that we get the item for.

Comment: Couldn't I just have a loop that goes through each item in the listview and checks for its value / text and returns the position of the item? what would that look like?

Comment: How do I control the comparison in getPosition(obj)? I have an array of Coin objects and I want to compare on the property of a private string in Coin.

Comment: @Don, we're not comparing anything, we're fetching the index of the object in the container. If you'd like to change how the index is fetched, look into overriding the `ArrayAdapter.getPosition(obj)`. Otherwise, you may be better off with a comparator and a built in sort function, if you need comparisons.

Comment: @Don, if you'd like to post a question and link it here or message me I'd be happy to look when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext, "The position of the clicked item is " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

in the listview `onItemClickListener()` that you will implement

Comment: It cant be in the onItemClickListener(). It has to be in the ArrayAdapter.

Comment: All I need is a for loop that checks each listview item for a value and returns the position of the item.